# How to achieve queueing of multiple spring batch jobs?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a usecase where a spring batch job (lets call it **BigBatchJob1**) is triggered from UI. This is a long running job and takes few hours to complete.

Now users want to queue up another instance of BigBatchJob , lets call it BigBatchJob2, before the BigBatchJob1 completes. Expectation is the BigBatchJob2 waits in the queue for BitBatchJob1 to complete and then start executing after BigBatchJob1 completes.

And user wants to queue up such jobs multiple times (BigBatchJob3,BigBatchJob4 etc..,) without waiting for previous ones to complete.

How to achieve this in spring batch?

Answer (score 0):

The `SimpleJobLauncher` provided by Spring Batch works with any `TaskExecutor` implementation. Some implementations have a queue behind the scene to store the submitted tasks (job instances in your case). You can make jobs run in sequence from the queue by using a single worker thread.

A more elaborate architecture is to put job requests in a separate physical queue and develop a listener to handle job requests in sequence (a bit similar to the approach described here: [Launching Batch Jobs through Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages)).